Finding unused variables after minimizing
After minimization (Python/scipy), I would like to know how to find unused variables in the result. Here is a simple example where the third variable is left untouched. Apart comparing initial value vs result, is there a better way to identify such variable?
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def objective(x):
    return -x[0] - x[1]

x0 = 0, 0, 1.234
res = minimize(objective, x0,
               bounds = ([-10,+10], [-10,+10], [-10,+10]))
print(res.x)

# output: [10.    10.     1.234]
# res.x[2] has been left untouched compared to x0[2]


Evaluate the objective with each value perturbed to see if it changes the result?

I would prefer a method based on the results. I went through the documentation for returned results but did not find anything.

I'm not aware of anything. Maybe explain your actual situation since in this case you wrote your objective function so you know which variables are used.

I'm trying to fit monkey data with several theories (prospect theory). The functions I used for the fit have several variables but I suspect some are useless in some cases.

The OptimizeResult (the return object of scipy.optimize.minimize) includes the Jacobian (jac). Points in the Jacobian that are 0 correspond to variables that have no impact on the result. You can check where those are using the following line:
import numpy as np

np.where(np.isclose(res.jac, 0.))[0]

In this example, it returns np.array([2]), since x[2] has no impact on the optimization.
Here we pass an array with 10 values and only use x[0] and x[4] in the optimization.
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def objective(x):
    return -x[0] - x[4]

x0 = np.ones(10)
res = minimize(objective, x0,
               bounds=([[-10, 10]]*len(x0)))
print(res.x)  # [10.  1.  1.  1. 10.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
print(np.where(np.isclose(res.jac, 0.))[0])  # [1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9]


I had suggested in the comments you could perturb the function, but then I remembered that you get the Jacobian, which is exactly that.

Does the Jacobian also give respective contribution of each variables to the minimatrion? For example, if I use -5*x[0] -x[1] in my example, I get [-5 -1 0].

The Jacobian is the vector of partial derivatives of the function with respect to each variable (though I'm not sure at what point it's evaluated at, I'd have to check the source code). So, if f(x0, x1, x2) = -5*x0-x1, the first term will be the partial derivative of f with respect to x0, which is -5. The second will be the partial derivative with respect to x1, which is -1. The last term is the partial derivative with respect to x2, which is 0.
